# Using "npm install" to install jquery-ui

Tags: jquery-ui, npm, npm-install

I see from here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui that jquery-ui's latest release is 1.11.4.  However, when I use "npm install jquery-ui", it's only 1.10.3.  I checked this version in `node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js`.

Is there any way for me to install the latest version?

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), how to use version!

Comment: I tried `npm install jquery-ui@latest`, but I still have 1.10.3

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I'm asking a stupid question.  Node is using a different repository...  not git...  I'm not sure how I should deal this question now.

Comment: As per jquery-ui website, 1.12 is the first version officially released to npm:
https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/#official-package-on-npm If you are willing to skip 1.11.* then you can use this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui

Answer (score 137):

jQuery-ui specifically needs to be build after installation. To avoid this, use `npm install jquery-ui-dist`

Comment: So, that package is maintained by you? Is there any connection to the jQuery team?

Comment: After jquery-ui 1.12 its possible to use the official package. See https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/#official-package-on-npm

Comment: I don't get why the jQuery package has a dist folder, but the jQuery UI package does not and there is instead a separate package for the distributable. Very inconsistent.

Comment: Or do a `npm install jquery-ui-dist --save` to get installed a a dependency.

Answer (score 17):

T J gave the right answer, but it is a bit short / too generic.

The GitHub project is at https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/

So the real command would be `npm install github:jquery/jquery-ui` (you can even skip `github:` as npm defaults to it).

But this would bring you the latest, unstable version (around 1.12 at time of writing), and it didn't even work when I tried.

So it is better to fetch a tagged version:

```
npm install github:jquery/jquery-ui#1.11.4
```

Generic note: AFAIK, if the project hasn't a `package.json` file, this kind of install can still fail.

Comment: This worked for me, getting and saving 1.12.0. Is there a way of checking if npm's version is outdated from the actual git source?

Comment: @BenSewards In general, I go to the NPM registry to see what version is listed (beware: several NPM entries can refer to the same GitHub project! I saw that with Angular UI Bootstrap, for example). Then I go to the GitHub project (referenced from the NPM page) and see the released versions (tagged). Some projects have no released version, alas.

Comment: @BenSewards: That's easy.  npm install $packagename.  As long as you leave off the "-S", it doesn't do any saving, and should output something like: "└── jquery-ui-dist@1.12.1"

Answer (score 6):

Here is the current latest version (1.11.4), same package that bower is using, including all themes.

`npm install github:components/jqueryui#1.11.4`

Answer (score 0):

You can install it like

```
npm install github:mygithubuser/myproject
```

as mentioned in the [install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) documentation