# Angular4 can't find Jquery-UI functions

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular, jquery-ui

I have installed Jquery and Jquery-ui

```
npm install --save jquery jquery-ui
```

The files are in the node_modules directory.
I have a component that declares Jquery

```
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

My jquery functions work just fine, but the jquery-ui functions do not.

```
$('some-div').dropdown(); // works
$('window').draggable(); // draggable is not recognized as a function
```

So, obviously my inclusion for jquery-ui is not correct. I tried including a bunch of different things in my .angular-cli.json page to no success.

Things I have tried in my .angular-cli file:

```
...
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable.js",
    "../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/draggable.js",
]
```

I tried importing directly into the component, but that gave problems with $ui being defined. I also got errors that defined is not defined.

I have looked at [npm jquery-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui) and [Jquery-ui Upgrade guides](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/)

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution to define jquery-ui in angular-cli.json (and avoid to add it in index.html) is:

1 : Import jquery-ui-dist

```
    npm install jquery jquery-ui-dist
```

2: Add scripts in angular-cli.json

```
    "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
       "../node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js"
    ],
```

Source :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38795318

Answer (score 8):

HOLY SMOKES! This one was very troublesome, but I figured it out after days of trying.

So, there are a lot of partial answers out there, but this should be complete. 
You cannot from what I have seen, include jquery-ui in your angular-cli and the index. The plugin inclusions will be overwritten and jquery as a global will be undefined.
I couldn't get it to work by using just the angular-cli.json, but I did get it to work by **only** using index inclusion.

Here is what needs to be done to only use index script inclusion for jquery/jquery-ui.

**1**: Uninstall jquery and jquery-ui and remove it from the package.json

```
npm uninstall --save jquery jquery-ui
```

**2**: Delete the node_modules folder

**3**: Delete any references to jquery or jquery-ui in you angular-cli.json file

**4**: Rebuild the node_modules folders (double check that jquery-ui is not there, but it doesn't really matter so long as the angular-cli.json doesn't have it included.

```
npm install
```

**5**: include jquery, then jquery-ui in your index file. I used 2.2.4, because I don't trust 3 yet.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**6**: In what ever component you want to utilize jquery or jquery plugin inject $

```
declare var $: any;

$('draggable').draggable(); // WORKS!
```

Comment: Where exactly do I put the declare, in the .ts file, .html file in a script tag?

Comment: @DanChase in the .ts file of the component you want to access jquery.

Comment: It works, but it throws an error "$" not found. This will cause build error later during deployment.

Answer (score 1):

please import jQuery ui to index.html like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And decare $ in your component like this

declare var $: any;

Comment: Is there a way to include this in .angular-cli.json file instead of a web import? The applications needs to work offline as well.

Comment: Hi Chris, you can use bower for that .  Like this:
    bower install jquery-ui  And then you can import that to both index.html and angular.cli.json.

Comment: I don't have bower. I am using npm.  I npm installed jquery-ui. I need to know how to include it in the .angular-cli file correctly and how to utilize it in my script like the example above. When I include the file directly I get an error for the draggable function still not being recognized.

Comment: Hi Chris, did you import jquery and jquery ui in specific component?  
Like this   
    import var $: any; // import jquery  
    import 'jquery-ui';

Comment: Could you show me an example of proper importing of Jquery-ui

Comment: ok, please do these steps:  
    npm i -S jquery jquery-ui
    and then import them to your component you want to use jquery-ui  
 eg: home.component.ts  
   import var $: any;
   import 'jquery-ui';
ok, that is all. please use them and vote me about this answer

Comment: I add the  jquery and jquery-ui script to my index. Tried importing var $: any and jquery-ui and I still get a draggable is not a function error.