# Include jquery-ui in Angular 5 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-ui

I am trying to add jquery-ui to my project in Angular 5 since I had to create a feature using jquery-ui, but i cannot get it to work. I get the error:

> TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10_jquery**(...).droppable is not
>   a function

I tried putting the jquery-ui script to my assets folder and load it in index.html, but that doesn't work since it loads before jquery. Now i used this code to add it in component where I use it, and it adds it after jquery but still get the error above:

```
if (!document.querySelector('script[src="./assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"]')) {
      const s = document.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.src = './assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js';
      document.head.appendChild(s);
    }
```

When i run npm install jquery-ui and add scripts to angular-cli.json, same error occurs... Dont know what else to try...

EDIT: This answer finally worked for me: [Angular4 can't find Jquery-UI functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512475/angular4-cant-find-jquery-ui-functions)

Comment: You should try this answer, worked well for Angular 10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45573919/11156666

Answer (score 5):

You can install `jquery-ui-dist` to avoid adding the file in your index file:

```
npm install jquery
npm install jquery-ui-dist
```

Add this in `script` inside `angular-cli.json`

```
 "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
 "../node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js"
```

Comment: There is no jquery-ui.js inside jquery-ui folder, it has ui/widgets folders, and inside widgets there are droppable.js, draggable.js etc.. Tried adding those but didn't work..

Comment: sorry install jquery-ui-dist to get the file

Comment: Still getting the same error... with dist installed