# Uncaught Reference error $ is not defined in Angular

Tags: angular

I am having some jquery script in "/src/assets/js/auth.js".

I have included the file and jquery plugin in angular.cli.json file.

**angular.cli.json:**

```
"scripts": [
    "../src/assets/js/auth.js",
    "../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
  ],
```

Finally I have imported jquery in the app.component.ts.

**app.component.ts:**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

To make sure whether jquery works or not, I have put the jquery code in ngOnInit() {} function and its works well.

But when I am placing it as an external js file, I will always return the error:
**Uncaught Reference error $ is not defined**

Please someone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: You should try this answer, worked well for Angular 10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45573919/11156666

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include jquery file before the plugin

```
"scripts": [
"../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
"../src/assets/js/auth.js",
  ],
```

And replace

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

with

```
declare let $: any;
```

Otherwise, jquery will work but $ will not contain the plugin's function