# Angular 6 ReferenceError: $ is not defined error with JQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have installed angular 6 with foundation but I am getting an error with JQuery.

> Uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected identifier
>   ReferenceError: $ is not defined

In my component, i have

```
declare var $:any

onNgInit () {
  $(document).foundation()
}
```

I have all imports in my angular.json

```
scripts : [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
]
```

I have tried everything I found on the internet but still facing the same error. Also to add this used to work when I was working with Angular 4

Comment: Try using `JQuery(document).foundation()`

Comment: Ahould be `jQuery(document).foundation()`

Comment: JQuery gives a squiggly line on (doucument) and also for the jquey, it gives a squiiggly line on foundation(). Do help me out most

Comment: For me adding the following to the **polyfills.ts** solved this issue

`import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
window['$'] = jQuery;`

Comment: @Gireesh your solution worked for me when nothing else would! Was having the problem with Angular 8.

Comment: @GireeshKudipudi your solution worked smoothly!

Comment: You should try this answer, worked well for Angular 10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45573919/11156666

Answer (score 11):

This is something related to the way ES6 modules isolation works. Loading from the `angular.json` file is the same as the script tag on an index.html file (the global scope). When you import it on any component you're getting a new local copy, so avoid importing it this way.

To prevent intellisense and compiling issues, create a `typings.d.ts` file with the following content:

```
declare var $: any;
declare var jQuery: any;
```

Now you're ready to go :)

Comment: Could you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198501/referenceerror-is-not-defined-in-angular. I thought your solution solved my issue but it doesn't unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

Install Jquery Plugin For angular

> npm install jquery --save

Now in your `app.module.ts` add

> import * as $ from "jquery";

It will make the work done.

Comment: I did tried this as other suggestions online but none of them worked

Comment: I get this    'foundation' does not exist on type
'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.

Answer (score 7):

If you have jquery installed and still getting this error. In every component where you are using `$` add at the top `import * as $ from "jquery";`

Answer (score 7):

Always take care that there are by default two "scripts" sections in angular.json. Most of the developers casually giving the reference in "scripts" tag like this...

```
scripts : [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
]
```

without verifying if they are adding this to test "script" or the "build" script...

However, just verify once that you are adding this to "build" section and not in "test" section in angular.json as this is the silly mistake a developer always do.

### wrong:

```
"test"{
   scripts : [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
   ]
}
```

### right:

```
"build"{
   scripts : [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
   ]
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just came to say that this answer just helped me.  I was setting up a new Angular project and a couple of our clients really like jQuery DataTables so obviously I needed jQuery and couldn't for the life of me figure out how something I've done quite a bit could just not work. It was this, put the script in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 4):

For me adding the following to the **polyfills.ts** solved this issue

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
window['$'] = jQuery;
```

**Note**: Added this as a comment to the question as well

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for an answer to this the solution is to import node types (I am assuming you have already used npm to install --save jquery and foundation-sites):

`npm install --save @types/node`

then in your `tsconfig.app.json` under your module, make sure the types section (under `compilerOptions`) reads:

`"types": ["node"]`

then in your code:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
const Foundation = require('foundation-sites'); 

.... other declarations etc... 

new Foundation.default.DropdownMenu($("#yourelementid"), {});
```

I'm using Dropdown menu as an example but this should work with all of the different foundation plugins (I have not tested though).

Comment: If I am using `Bootstrap`, would this work? My concern is `Bootstrap` also requires `JQuery` so would my application have two versions of `Jquery`?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your path is correct ?

try this
[../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js]

Comment: The path has been changed in Angualar 6 , the path you have written doesnt work anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the jQuery types, I do this after I install jQuery from npm.

> npm install --save-dev @types/jquery

Answer (score 0):

For me executing
npm i core-js
worked. hope this helps you too

Answer (score 0):

I tried several solutions, finally it worked by inserting the style directly in the style.css then the global one, then I inserted the js function in the app.component.ts and the code directly in the app.componet.html, after doing this and seeing that it worked, I moved everything into a component.

Try to look this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slick-carousel-r7u74h

Comment: Please try putting explanation from the linked URl instead of just posting the URL.