# ReferenceError: $ is not defined in Angular

Tags: angular6

I want to show a dialog box when my application starts but I am getting error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` even though I have defined it like `declare var $: any;`. The demo is at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnwe2c

If you check the console, you'll see the error.

I have defined an `DialogComponent` which is simply `Bootstrap` modal in `dialog.component.html`. It has a method `showDialog` which call's `Bootstrap`'s `modal` method `$(this.dialogRef.nativeElement).modal('show');`.

In `app.component.html`, I am using the `DialogComponent` - `<app-dialog-box #dialogBox ></app-dialog-box>`. The `AppComponent` takes an `Input` and depending on the `Input`, it decides whether to show the dialog box or nott

App.component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    if(this.signup!=""){
      if(this.signup === "success") {
      this.showDialog("Signup was successful")
      }else if(this.signup === "error") {
        this.showDialog("Error: Signup wasn't successful")
      } else {
        this.showDialog("Unrecognised message: "+this.signup)
      }
    }

  }
```

In index.html
`<my-app [signup]="'success'">loading</my-app>`

Also, in `index.html`, I am loading all the `javascripts` and `jquery` before using `my-app` so I expect that `$` should be available.

UPDATE - 
Here is an interesting behaviour. When I run the app for first time using https://angular-gnwe2c.stackblitz.io, I don't see the dialog box and see error in console ReferenceError: $ is not defined, But if I change the code (say type an Enter, Stackblitz refreshes the code and the dialog box pops! I think when the app is loading initially, jquery isn't downloaded but when I change the code, jquery is available at that time

Comment: what is your angular version

Comment: I am using Angular6

Comment: try this Way https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: Here is an interesting behaviour. When I run the app for first time using `https://angular-gnwe2c.stackblitz.io`,  I don't see the dialog box and see error in console `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, But if I change the code (say type an Enter, Stackblitz refreshes the code and the dialog box pops! I think when the app is loading initially, jquery isn't downloaded but when I change the code, jquery is available at that time.

Comment: I am not using `Materialise`, I am using `Bootstrap`.

Comment: You should try this answer, worked well for Angular 10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45573919/11156666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve the issue in `Stackblitz` but in my application, I was able to resolve the issue by changing the order of loading of scripts

My application was being served using `Play` framework. The original code was

```
<app-root signup=@signup> 
    </app-root>

        @* Built Angular bundles *@
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/polyfills.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/runtime.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/vendor.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/styles.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I changed the order and moved `jquery` and `bootstrap` before Angular's package

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/polyfills.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/runtime.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/vendor.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/styles.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to include scripts into `index.html` manually. All necessary packages should be installed via `npm`.

Changed [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yoy3b2?file=src/app/dialog/dialog.component.ts)  from original question - added imports for `boostrap` and `jquery` into `dialog.component.ts`. And then installed missing dependencies - `jquery`, `bootstrap` and `popper.js` packages.

Hope this helps!